# What is the main difference between JavaSE and JavaEE?

Tags: java

I do not have a clear idea what the main difference between JavaSE and JavaEE is!
I would like to know whether JavaSE is a subset of JavaEE or JavaEE is totally different from JavaSE. I also like to know whether JavaEE JDK includes all of the classes and API libraries included in JavaSE.

If I install JavaEE JDK on my PC can I then install NetBeans? What will be the advantages?

Comment: Dang! Google and Wikipedia are down **again**? I hate when that happens!

Comment: @Hovercraft - The fact that a question can be answered by Google or Wikipedia doesn't necessarily make it a bad question for this site.

Comment: @Brendan: No, but the original poster's simplistic post shows that he hasn't taken the first least effort to check out these resources before posting this very simplistic question. If he had, he'd have been able to post a much more specific and intelligent question about points of misunderstanding rather than a general, need to write a book chapter to answer, "what's this" type question. It's not wrong of me to ask for a little demonstration of personal effort and initiative, is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Java SE/EE/ME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me)

Comment: @Hovercraft, for an apprentice it might even be hard to understand properly what you've just read.  What search terms do you have to use with Google to get a clear, simple explanation useful for grandmothers?

Answer (score 1):

Java Platform, Enterprise Edition or Java EE is a widely used platform for server programming in the Java programming language. The Java platform (Enterprise Edition) differs from the Java Standard Edition Platform (Java SE) in that it adds libraries which provide functionality to deploy fault-tolerant, distributed, multi-tier Java software, based largely on modular components running on an application server.

In JavaEE you can develop enterprise level web applications using javaSE libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In a way yeah, you can say JavaSE is a subset of JavaEE. It adds more libraries that make deployment and development of enterprise applications easier. So, it includes all the libraries and more that are part of JavaSE.

You can install javaEE SDK on your PC and install netbeans. It is also possible with just javaSE SDK. Java EE is more advantageous (more bulky) if you are developing enterprise apps(more scable, distributed etc..)