# Running a jar file(not a runnable jar)

Tags: java, mobile, jar, manifest, program-entry-point

I just downloaded a mobile app jar from mobile9.com,I tried running it but then found out it wasnt a `runnable jar`.
So I would like to know is there a way to find out where the main is located in the .jar file.
Or can the jar file be only executed on mobile platforms?
Also I would like to know how does the mobile run the jar file without knowing about the main file in the `MANIFEST` file?

**UPDATE**
I tried searching for the `main`  but couldnt find it in the classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me, see the differences b/w Java ME, SE

Comment: kk..thnx..so looks like mobile apps dont use main but instead use midlet?Am I right?\

Comment: Yeah... a good article is also found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169501/J2ME-Hello-World-Mobile-Application