# Java EE application can be run on Java Micro edition or not?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me, embedded-linux

I have written a `Java EE application` and build a jar of it. I'm trying to run it on a embedded device which having `Embedded Linux` with `ARMv7` processor. Currently I have installed `Embedded Java Standard edition` of version `1.8` but it's taking lot of time for execution. Even simple java program is taking significatnt amount of time.
I read about `Java Micro Edition`. Before installing it, I wanted to confirm whether it's possible to run the application developed in `Java EE`.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

To have a better understanding, please see "[Difference between Java SE/EE/ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me#answer-2857791)".

Java EE usually runs inside a Java EE Server (e.g. GlassFish) and is intended for server-side applications or other large-scale systems.

What you probably want is to develop a **client** that will communicate with the Java EE program deployed on the server.

Comment: You mean to say that I have to write the application in JavaME which will run on my embedded device instead of Java EE application...??

Comment: Probably yes, but it really depends on what your _Java EE Application_ is trying to do. Java EE is actually a set of APIs and specifications for different technologies (Servlet, JMS, CDI, EJB, etc.,). If you are not using any of those, you are not doing Java EE. You can have your client logic on Java ME and you business logic on Java EE.