# Quickbooks Java IDE Requirement

Tags: java, quickbooks

I have installed `Netbeans Java SE` to work on sample application to integrate with `Quickbooks`.

But I'm wondering, is it enough? Or do I need to use `Java EE` version on my netbeans?

Comment: If you don't know the difference, and we don't know what kind of application you're writing then you're not going to get a great answer. Use SE (probably).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Java SE/EE/ME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me)

Comment: The Quickbooks SDK is perfectly usable by Java SE. If you're just developing a "sample application", it sounds like Java EE would be overkill.

Comment: @4castle thanks. i'll just stay on Java SE version then.