# Java EE container internals

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ioc-container

As a Java EE newbie having a background in Java SE, I don't quite understand what the Java EE, especially those buzzwords like `web container`,`Jave EE container` mean.

What I know that to run a java program, you need to call `java` with `classpath` set to dependencies (normally `.jar`) and an also an entry class with static main method.

I think to start Java EE programs, there is no difference than calling `java`, right? So are containers most of the time just `.jar` files that contains implementation of Java EE standard annotations?

Are containers like JBOSS just a bunch of libraries that are used to support the so-called "enterprise applications" involving transactions, security and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java SE = Standard Edition. This is the core Java programming
>   platform. It contains all of the libraries and APIs that any Java
>   programmer should learn (java.lang, java.io, java.math, java.net,
>   java.util, etc...).
>
> Java EE = Enterprise Edition. From Wikipedia:
>
> The Java platform (Enterprise Edition) differs from the Java Standard
>   Edition Platform (Java SE) in that it adds libraries which provide
>   functionality to deploy fault-tolerant, distributed, multi-tier Java
>   software, based largely on modular components running on an
>   application server. In other words, if your application demands a very
>   large scale, distributed system, then you should consider using Java
>   EE. Built on top of Java SE, it provides libraries for database access
>   (JDBC, JPA), remote method invocation (RMI), messaging (JMS), web
>   services, XML processing, and defines standard APIs for Enterprise
>   JavaBeans, servlets, portlets, Java Server Pages, etc...

Source: [Difference between Java SE/EE/ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me)