# How do know if my application is using Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a servlet application with JPA and Vaadin, it's running on GlassFish server.
Am I using Java EE here? Or is still Java SE?

Comment: It's Java EE of course. If it's servlet application, SE don't have that kind of feature. But SE is the core of your program in java.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from the answer? How is this important?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Java SE/EE/ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857376/difference-between-java-se-ee-me)

Comment: Thanks! I was 99% sure, but I needed this 1% to be definitely sure. I know how stupid was this question, but it was important for me to know.

Comment: Why is it important to you?

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are not part of Java SE, but of Java EE. So you are using Java SE and some parts of Java EE.

Answer (score 1):

SE doesn't come with server or any other software stack so If your application is using above tools there is a higher chance that your application is using EE here.

Comment: Btw Glassfish server is a part of JAVA EE

Comment: Glassfish isn't part of Java EE, it is (contains) an implementation of Java EE.

Comment: Indeed its an implementation of JAVA EE but it also comes as part of software stack with Java EE.

Comment: Java EE is a set of specifications and interfaces, glassfish is an implementation. It is not Java EE itself (ask IBM, or other companies that offer competing implementations of Java EE).

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/whats-the-relationship-between-java-ee-and-glassfish