# Has there different JDKs or JVMs on each Java platforms?

Tags: java

I am confused about java platforms.From the page [Differences between Java EE and Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html) , java has four platforms. Has there any special things between them ? Are they use different JDKs or JREs ?

For clear my question , when I download JDK , I think I can create not only java desktop applications *(with swing or javafx)* but also web applications.If so ,why java says it has different platforms. If yes , it should has different jdk or jvm for each specific platform. As I think , different platforms mean I need to download different version of JDK. For instance , I need to download JDK for JavaEE platform which contains API for JavaEE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065240/whats-the-main-difference-between-java-se-and-java-ee

Comment: I talk to someone , ***java has four platforms java-se,java-ee,java-me,javafx*** . He asked me back `Can I create four types of applications with one jdk ? Has there some jdks for each platform ?If I can create all with this JDK why java says it has four platforms ?`  ... How to answer him ?

Comment: Java 7 documentation says that there are 3 platforms and JavaFX is part of Java SE

Comment: @mjn Thank you ... the link I described may aim for Java8

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: This is a legitimate Question. [That official article](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html) from Oracle is confusing, listing FX as a separate platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends (like often).

The JDK is a development kit for Java SE including FX. So you can develop desktop applications but also web applications depending on the type of integration you prefer. The Java EE SDK contains also the Glassfish server, examples and tutorials but they are not really needed. The ME is a special minimized versions for embedded device development including special tools for that.

I am developing web application for years with a Java SE JDK only. As I normally use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) with an embedded container or install a [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) on demand, this works perfectly and the Java EE SDK is not needed.

Comment: As your answer ,If I have plan to create ME application , do you mean I need to download jdk for ME edition and it has specific libraries for macro devices ?

Comment: I never saw different jdk or jvm for specific platforms.

Comment: Also, that article looks old, and in the old days early days of JavaFX, these early versions of FX were shipped separately. Only later was it bundled with Java SE. Being a separate download at that time may have been the reason for that article’s listing it as a separate platform.

Comment: @Cataclysm beside the JDK there are downloads for the Java EE SDK and the ME SDK